# Remove nodes from loaded iframe

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, memory

### Context

**parent.html** with two buttons with the following roles:

- **Load** into an iframe another document (child.html).
- **Unload** the child document.

**child.html** has a script that creates *n* number of nodes and pushes strings into an array (to exemplify memory usage over time).

#### Sample Code

**parent.html**:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <button onclick="loadGame()">Load</button>
  <button onclick="unloadGame()">Unload</button>
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <script>
    var loadGame, unloadGame;

    loadGame = function() {
      var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.className = 'loader--iframe';
      iframe.src = 'child.html';
      document.querySelector('.loader').appendChild(iframe);
    };
    unloadGame = function() {
      document.querySelector('.loader')
        .removeChild(document.querySelector('.loader--iframe'));
    };
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**child.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <p>Loaded Content</p>
  <script>
    (function(){
      var i, el = null,
        x = [];

      for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        el = document.createElement('div');
        el.innerHTML = 'node ' + i;
        document.body.appendChild(el);
      }
      x.push(new Array(1000000).join('x'));
    })()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

There's also a gist to easily test it on your host:

```
git clone https://gist.github.com/am/b7c7c762e9064dc9c7fc93e13eb8c0a9
cd b7c7c762e9064dc9c7fc93e13eb8c0a9
bash run.sh
```

### Problem

After loading and unloading a few times, using [chrome-devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) Performance > memory record, I see that memory, documents and nodes don't get totally cleaned up:

Start:

- JS Heap: 3 857 912
- Document: 2
- Nodes: 22

End:

- JS Heap: 5 908 928
- Document: 4
- Nodes: 21 672

[image]

Note: The test was run using incognito browser window without extensions loaded.

### Expectation

I'm trying to find a way to load html content into a page, but at some point be able to unload the content ensuring all memory taken by that child is also released. So the main doubts are:

1. **Is this the expected browser behaviour?**
2. **Is there any way to fully remove the child nodes, document and memory allocation?**